# how to find the maximum value of array elements in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a list of countries, their cities and numbers of people living in them. I need to find the city with the smallest number of people of each country:

data given:

```
Springfield USA 16876
Xao China 1477555
Getfield UK 812 
Sheffield USA 18600
Joji India 5565
Huffington USA 7891
Saji India 774
Pubfield UK 332 
Ming China 4555
Lao China 502
```

the result has to be:

```
Huffington 7891
Lao 502
Pubfield 332
Saji 774
```

what's the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Do you want/need array? Part of the process in design is choosing data structures. I'd first go for map of strings to sets of a custom struct which contains city and size (and is ordered by the latter). Then you can iterate over the map and the sets are always ordered. Unless performance issues, I'd go for this as it describes the problem well.

Comment: Arrays are not necessary, I have tried finding the smallest value of the city and eliminating it, then finding anotherone by eliminatinig the previous and repeating the same but with different country. However it is very unefficient. @StephanLechner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the data in a vector, then sort the vector

```
struct City {
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int population;
};
std::vector<City> cities;
```

And then sort them based on population:

```
std::sort(cities.begin(), cities.end(), 
     [](City& a, City& b) { return a.population > b.population; });
```

Then remove the lowest items.

**EDIT**
Here is a different version that creates a vector of lowest populations by country.

First, change the `sort` to sort by country *and* population:

```
std::sort(cities.begin(), cities.end(), 
    [](City& a, City& b) {
        if (a.country == b.country) {
            return a.population < b.population;
        }
        else {
            return a.country.compare(b.country) < 0;
        }
    });
```

Now, create a second vector with smallest populations:

```
// Copy
std::vector<City> countries = cities;
// Remove duplicates.
// Note this works in our case because of the way the vector is sorted
auto it = std::unique(countries.begin(), countries.end(),
    [](City& a, City& b) { return a.country == b.country; });
countries.resize(std::distance(countries.begin(), it));
```

At this point, the `countries` vector looks like this:

```
Lao China 502
Saji India 774
Pubfield UK 332
Huffington USA 7891
```

Comment: Due to the "of each country" requirement, I would suggest first sorting it by country, then sorting each country's section by population.  This guarantees that, depending on the comparison function supplied to `std::sort()`, either the first or last entry for any given country will contain the smallest population for that country.

Comment: Good catch Justin.  That answer isn't actually going to give the correct result according to the requirement.  I'm also unclear whether it would give the most "efficient" solution either.  If this is a trivia question about efficiency then that would be the kind of question that would elicit a lot of debate.  I agree with the approach because it gets close to a correct answer but it certainly isn't guaranteed to be the most efficient.

Comment: @JustinTime You are correct. I missed that part of the original post. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @shawn1874 My goal was clarity over performance. If the list is relatively small or the sorting is not done very often, this algorithm should be fine. OP does not mention how large the list might be or how important speed is.

Comment: that's fine with me.  The words "most efficient" are ambiguous as different people could mean different things, and the OP accepted your answer so that is what matters most.  I agree with your general approach to solving a problem but I thought maybe the OP meant performance when he asked for the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know from advance which countries you will have.

You can create a map of a "string" and "int", and also an array of cities where the size will be the same as the size of the map.

In the map the "string" is names of the country and the "int" is the number of people you have in a country.

Then iterate over the list and check for each item if it's have the smallest number of people.
and write the name of the particular city in the array.